# Procedure Entry Point could not be located: Qt MinGw CPP Desktop App crashes when run

Tags: c++, qt, dll, runtime-error, mingw

In my Qt Desktop app, I have included the `<filesystem>` in one of my .cpp files. When I compiled it with the MinGw 8.2 version there were errors everywhere. I tried downloading MinGw through MSyS2 and now the application compiles successfully. However, when I try to run it, it crashes, and shows me this error:

[image]

Comment: That message indicates that the C++ runtime library being loaded is either not found or not the correct version.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie what could I possibly do/check to fix the problem? Any suggestions?

Comment: It might be that you built your application against one library, but run it with another one. I.e. your build and runtime libraries are different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your application is loaded with a dynamic library which is not same version with the dynamic library that you build your application against。
You can find out the dll which your application was built against and put it into the directory where your application is